# How to select just the rows in a table that fit a criteria , avoiding duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, filter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a df like follows:

```
USER Value object 
0001     V      V
0002     A   NULL
0002     C      C
0003     A   NULL
0004     A   NULL
0004     A   NULL
0003     V      V
```

So I basically want `USER` to be the unique id for each row of this DF. If there is an `A` in the `Value` column, I only want it if that's the only option for the ID. So there are two `002`'s, I only want to see the instance where it is not `A` , so `C`.

Because `0004` doesn't have a non-`A` `Value`, I'll take the `A`.

Final result:

```
USER Value
0001     V
0002     C
0003     V
0004     A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following:

```
select      user,
            'A' as value
from        tbl
group by    user
having      sum(case when value = 'A'  then 1 else 0 end) > 0
        and sum(case when value <> 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
union all
select      user,
            value
from        tbl
where       value <> 'A'
order by    user;
```

See Fiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b28f4c/2/0

The desired result is achieved with your example data. However, your example data does not contain any users having more than one non-A value row. The above query will keep all of them. If you only want to keep one or some, explain how to pick which you want.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the one Value per tuple, returning A at last resort (if A is the smallest of the potential values):

```
select USER, max(Value) as value from Table
group by User
```

or, this might return multiple users if they have several tuples with different object (when not null)

```
select distinct user, coalesce(object, value) 
from table ;
```

Comment: Close but it is a string, max will not work. Option 1 is closer to what i need tho

Comment: @JohnThomas just ascii() the string and max works :-)

Comment: @JohnThomas not sure what you mean by "if it is a string, max will not work". Max also works on strings (uses the collate sequence of the string as defined in the create table, lexicographical order by default).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution if you don't like typing :-)

```
select 
    distinct USR
            ,VAL 
from 
    TBL 
qualify 
    max(ascii(VAL)) over (partition by USR ) = ascii(VAL)
```

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run in snowflake:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE  tbl( USR  varchar(4),  VAL varchar(1),  OBJ varchar(4));    
INSERT INTO  tbl (USR,VAL,OBJ)
VALUES
('0001', 'V', 'V'),
('0002', 'A', NULL),
('0002', 'C', 'C'),
('0003', 'A', NULL),
('0004', 'A', NULL),
('0004', 'A', NULL),
('0003', 'V', 'V');

select 
    distinct USR
            ,VAL 
from 
    TBL 
qualify 
    max(ascii(VAL)) over (partition by USR ) = ascii(VAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following if you are using SQL-Server

```
select distinct USER
               ,Value
from 
(
     select *,rank() over (partition by USER order by Value desc) as ranking
     from your_table_name
) as t
where ranking =1
```